# How to reverse tether the internet connection via wifi

Tags: wireless, internet, hot-spot

How to share by internet (from my internal gsm card) via wifi?

I can share my gsm internet from Android, but whats about the other way around?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the questions tagged 'hot-spot' ?

Answer (score 1):

Create the wifi hotspot via "Create new wireless network" from the network connections menu.